# contextMenu in uicontrol popupmenu opened

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I have in my GUI an uicontrol of style popupmenu (combobox).

This popupmenu is filled directly when the GUI user load file in the program.

My question is : Is there a way to implement a context menu on a right-click directly on an item of the popupmenu opened ?

The basic context menu in the uicontrol properties is only working on the first line of the popupmenu but not on the items of the list ...

The idea is to be able to right-click in order to make operations (like delete) on the selected item

Comment: Look at [this](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/setting-listbox-mouse-actions) page from Undocumented Matlab. That should get you going